# Regex for mobile phone number only in one format

Tags: regex

I have the following regex expression

```
^((\+48))[ ]?[0-9]{3}[ ]?[0-9]{3}[ ]?[0-9]{3}$
```

to accept only `+48 123 123 123`

but it accepts numbers without spaces. How to change it ?

Comment: Also, you can simplify the thing a bit by using another quantifier; `^\+48(?: \d{3}){3}$`. The `?:` is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `?` of the `[ ]?` parts, the `?` makes it optional.

Comment: but I want spaces in the phone number

Comment: It should still match spaces, but those should not be optional. Hence he should remove only the `?` but leave in a space. It does not have to be inside brackets though. @Tony the question mark (`?`) means the spaces are *optional*, so it also matches without them. If you remove the question mark it should then work.

Comment: @Tony you should accept the answer if this solved your problem and vote up the comment of Daniël Knippers if this helped to clarify the answer. Kind regards.

Comment: I know, I had to wait 10 minutes to accept this answer